# List sections of chapter at beginning of that chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, minitoc

How can one have a mini table of contents for the current chapter appear just after the chapter name listing all sections of that chapter?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Have a look at the [`minitoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package.
Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\dominitoc% Initialization
\tableofcontents

\chapter{bla}
\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc

\section{blubb}

\section{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}, at minitoc is contents, not in Vietnamese. Please help me.

Comment: `\usepackage[vietnam]{minitoc}`

Comment: In case minitoc content does not appear, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146461/minitoc-not-appear

Answer (score 40):

more info here http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minitoc/

for minitoc to be visible you need both `\dominitoc` `\tableofcontents`

you can change how deep minitoc goes:

```
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1}    % Show until sections in minitoc

\setcounter{minitocdepth}{3}    % Show until subsubsections in minitoc
```

**edit 1:** more about formating minitoc (insert in preamble)

```
\dominitoc[n]      % [n] removes the title "contents"
```

(this inserts minitoc and won't work without toc

```
\dominitoc[c]      % [c] centers the title "contents"
```

(someone please edit how other parameters should be added: [n][v] or [n, c], even if this is not a good example as as c and n don't go together)

```
\nomtcrule         % removes rules = horizontal lines

\nomtcpagenumbers  % remove page numbers from minitocs

\undotted          % removes just the dots
```

you did not ask for this but you can also have minilof (for figures) and minilot (for tables)

Comment: `\tableofcontents` is not necessary for creating minitocs - you could use `\faketableofcontents` instead.

Answer (score 14):

You can also do this with the [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package, and avoid some of the interactions that `minitoc` sometimes has.  See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5944/minitoc-and-memoir/7877#7877) for an example. (Although the example uses memoir, `titletoc` can be used with any of the regular document classes too.)