# Minitoc and memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, minitoc

I read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/list-sections-of-chapter-at-beginning-of-that-chapter) about `minitoc` but I can't make it work with `memoir`. Is there an known incompatibility between these two ?

Is it somehow possible to make it work ?

Comment: have you checked the memoir manual for a minitoc equivalent? I would be surprised if memoir didn't have it's own implementation of minitoc, as it has this for a lot of packages.

Comment: I checked, it seems it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are compatibility problems between `minitoc` and `memoir`.

To work it out, I recommend to update minitoc to the latest version. Further check out the section *2.22 Use with the memoir class* in the current [minitoc documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minitoc/minitoc.pdf). There's even a package `mtcpatchmem.sty` which patches the memoir class to make both work together. The `minitoc` documentation tells more.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I gave up, I never managed to have something working. I read the doc, I discovered I had problems with unnumbered chapters, tried to correct but still...

Comment: Is minitoc important for you? In that case you might consider to use scrbook instead of memoir. Very much of the memoir features come from packages that can be loaded with scrbook. I must admit that the KOMA classes are my favorite classes.

Comment: It was more a test than a real need. I'll have a look at KOMA; but now I invested quite a lot of time tuning the document with `memoir` ...

Comment: @CedricH.: My experience, although probably not as illustrious, is different from Stefan's. I'm currently using minitoc to provide part-level minitocs, with memoir, without problems. The minitoc document says there shouldn't be a problem after memoir [2005/09/25], and that the patch is for that. One more thing: I'm loading minitoc *after* hyperref. If you'd care to post an MWP, we could all look into it a bit deeper.

Answer (score 19):

You can replicate most (all?) of the functionality of `minitoc` with the `titletoc` package, which is I think is compatible with memoir.  Here's a basic example:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
  \startcontents[chapters]
  \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}

  \section{Section}
    \lipsum[1]  
  \section{Section 2}
    \lipsum

\chapter{Second chapter}
  \startcontents[chapters]
  \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}

  \section{Section}
    \lipsum[2]
  \section{Another section}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\contentsmargin{1em}`?

Comment: @lpdbw Not really needed. I'll take it out of the example. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Do you know how I can remove the indent in front of section numbers in the partial ToC (not in the normal ToC)?

Comment: You need to make a separate `\titlecontents` command for the partial contents.  Perhaps you can ask this as a separate question, as it's a good general question about how to use `titletoc` that would be useful to have on the site.

Comment: OK, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66345/16865