# minitoc per sections with memoir

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, memoir, minitoc

I want to make a minitoc for each section with the subsections with the `memoir` class. But it doesn't works, only `\minitoc` per chapters are working.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Memoir and minitoc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5944/2693). You can use `titletoc` instead.

Comment: @AlanMunn The linked question doesn't seem to handle the case of per-section ToCs.

Comment: @lockstep Well to the extent that getting section TOCs just involves replacing 'chapters' with 'sections' and putting the commands after each `\section` instead of after each `\chapter` in my answer, I think they're pretty much the same.  I can post an almost duplicate answer here if you like.

Comment: @AlanMunn I tried `\dosecttoc` and `\secttoc`, and they worked with the `article` *class*, but not with `memoir`s `article` *option*. I 'd upvote a working solution for the latter case.

Comment: @lockstep Well my solution doesn't use `minitoc`.  So maybe it's better to have a clearer answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are well-known incompatibilities between `memoir` and `minitoc`.  However, the `titltoc` package can also produce section and chapter contents lists.  Here's an example based on my answer to this question:  [Minitoc and memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5944/2693) which shows how you can use `titletoc` to do section TOCs.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\settocdepth{subsubsection}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\kant[1]
\section{Section}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{2}{}
\subsection{A subsection}
\kant[2]
\subsection{Another subsection}
\kant[3]
\section{Section 2}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{2}{}
\subsection{A subsection}
\kant[4]
\subsection{Another subsection}
\kant[5]
\section{Section 3}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{2}{}
\subsection{A subsection}
\kant[6]
\subsection{Another subsection}
\kant[7]
\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]

Comment: Unfortunately, it bugs with hyperref.

Comment: @benlaug Your comment isn't very explicit. Adding `hyperref` to this example works properly, so if you are having a problem with `hyperref` you should ask a separate question about that. Did you remove all the auxiliary files? Did you load `hyperref` as the *last* package in the loading order?

Comment: It seems that putting hyperref as the last package is working ! Thank you very much for your help :).

Comment: @benlaug Yes, `hyperref` has to modify the behaviour of  a lot of packages and so should almost always be the last package you load. (There are a few exceptions in the case of *other* packages that affect `hyperref` itself, but generally loading it last is the best strategy.)