# Footnote in arabic with polyglossia

Tags: footnotes, polyglossia, right-to-left

writing a book in arabic, I want to make some comments by footnotes, in english and in arabic. The footnotes in arabic are from Right to Left, and I can put the rule of the footnote on the right side of the page. By the same, the english footnote (in the english environment) is from Left to Right, and I put the rule on the left side. In the case when I have two footnotes, in arabic and in english, in the same page, I want to have two rules of the footnotes in the same time, on the left and on the right side of the page, because of the two footnotes (in the page 3 of my ECM, I want to have a rule below the arabic footnote too...). Any one have an idea for that ? Thank you...

I post a minimal example...

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\def\efootnote#1{\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\raggedright\vspace*{-3pt}\rule{2in}{0.4pt}\vspace*{2.6pt}}\begin{english}
\hspace*{-5pt}\footnote{\hspace*{2pt}\LR{#1}}\end{english}}
\def\afootnote#1{\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\raggedleft\vspace*{-3pt}\rule{2in}{0.4pt}\vspace*{2.6pt}}\footnote{\hspace*{2pt}\RL{#1}}}


\begin{document}\LR{
Page with english footnote\efootnote{English footnote}
\newpage
Page with arabic footnote\afootnote{هامش عربي \LR{Arabic footnote}}
\newpage
Page with english\efootnote{English footnote} and arabic\afootnote{هامش عربي \LR{Arabic footnote}} footnotes.
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `bidi` package has already implemented what I think is the most reasonable way to handle a mixture of RTL and LTR footnotes: it provides a full width footnote rule. This will always be a much more reliable situation than trying to add a rule for the left and right footnotes independently. The reason for this becomes clear if you think of two long footnotes, LTR and the other RTL. The second footnote must be aligned vertically *after* the first footnote, and so its footnote rule will never be aligned with the first rule.

So the following is what I think is the best solution to your problem (even though it's not exactly what you ask for).

[The previous solution I posted based on `manyfoot` I don't think is workable after all, so I have removed it entirely; the curious can see the edit history for details.]

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Scheherazade}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Scheherazade}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\zmakeperpage{footnote}
\textwidthfootnoterule

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\begin{english}
Page with english footnote\footnote{English footnote}
\newpage
Page with arabic footnote\RTLfootnote{هامش عربي \LR{Arabic footnote}}
\newpage
Page with english\footnote{English footnote} and arabic\RTLfootnote{هامش عربي \LR{Arabic footnote}} footnotes.
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

[image: footnote image]

---

*Some comments on using `minitoc` (not relevant to the question directly)*

As an aside, I don't recommend using `minitoc` with `titlesec`.  If you require section/chapter TOCs you can use the `titletoc` package (documented with `titlesec`) to achieve the same aim, but preserving full compatibility with `titlesec`.  See the following questions for some examples of its use: [Minitoc and memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5944/2693) and [How to remove section indentation in partial ToC using titletoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66345/2693)

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your idea. But I need the minitoc package I have to implement this macro..

Comment: For the numerotation I have no need of it,I use this command..

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\hspace*{5pt}\fnsymbol{footnote}}

Comment: I will remove the comments about `minitoc`, since they are not relevant to my answer.

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Could you delete your comments about `minitoc`, now that I've edited the answer?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you re-post the discussion about the alternative of minitoc for use your solution please

Comment: I'm trying step by step my files and it seems good.. but why the rule on the right is higher from the english rule on the left . Ho can we pull down the arabic rule ?

Comment: Using a different rule for each set of footnotes will always lead to difficulties.  Honestly, I would suggest using the `\textwidthfootnoterule` command from `bidi` plus it which will put a single full width line for all footnotes. If you use that technique, you don't need my solution at all, but instead can (mainly) use `bidi` plus the `zref-perpage` package. I will add that to my solution.

Comment: Ok The solution you propose seems to be useful. Thanks. But I think that a more useful is that gives choice between the common footnoterule (the small one) when you have only one type of footnote (LTR or RTL) and that you propose \textwidthfootnoterule when you have the two types in the same page. Do you have an idea about that.. or a counter-idea !