# How to automate minitoc call?

Tags: minitoc

I'm using `minitoc` package and I would like to automate the command `\minitoc` after every chapter.

I'm looking a command to put in my preamble in the spirit of the following (which doesn't work):

```
\AtBeginChapter[]{\minitoc}
```

### MWE

The game is to remove every `\minitoc` with only one command in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\faketableofcontents

\chapter{chapter 1}
\minitoc

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\chapter{chapter 2}
\minitoc

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\chapter{chapter 3}
\minitoc

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\chapter{chapter 4}
\minitoc

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\chapter{chapter 5}
\minitoc

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\chapter{chapter 6}
\minitoc

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might also like the `titletoc` package for this - it is demonstrated, for example, in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7877/6621

Answer (score 5):

[`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) sets the chapter heading with `\@makechapterhead`:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

Ideally we'd like to insert `\minitoc` at the end of this macro, just after `\vskip 40\p@`, which would be equivalent to your usage of

```
\chapter{...}
\minitoc
```

We can use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch this macro, inserting `\minitoc` after the vertical skip - my `<search>` tag for the appropriate insertion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox,minitoc}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {40\p@}% <search>
  {40\p@\minitoc}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\faketableofcontents

\chapter{chapter 1}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\chapter{chapter 2}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\chapter{chapter 3}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\chapter{chapter 4}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\chapter{chapter 5}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\chapter{chapter 6}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

If you wish to have the same automated insertion for `\chapter*`, you can perform the same patch for `\@makeschapterhead`.

Note that this will not work if you use other sectional packages since the formatting of `\@makechapterheading` may be different.

Comment: Nice answer but a little bit complicated. Beamer has  `\AtBeginSection[]{}` command to automatically add something at every section. I'm surprised there is no equivalent command for book class.

Comment: @ppr: You're referring to the default classes which provide sufficient yet basic layout components. More modern classes (perhaps [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) and [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes) provide hooks into many components of the document structure... `book` not so much.