# Automatic partial toc at every chapter using titletoc

Tags: macros, chapters, koma-script, titletoc

This great answer [Minitoc and memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5944/minitoc-and-memoir/7877#7877) describes know how to put a chapter toc at the beginning of every chapter with the package `titletoc` using

```
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
```

I am looking for a way to automate this for every non-starred chapter in `scrbook` (in the sense that one does not have to type the two lines after every `\chapter` command), probably modifying the chapter definition slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it (now tested).

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\originalchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalchapter*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\originalchapter{#3}}
      {\originalchapter[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
}
```

Comment: There is a problem, it appears also on the main toc page, the listoffigures and listoftables pages also. How to turn it off on these pages?