# Automated partial TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List sections of chapter at beginning of that chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/list-sections-of-chapter-at-beginning-of-that-chapter)

Hello,

I need to make a small chapter TOC at each chapter. What I need is something like:

### Chapter 3 - Chapter 3 name

```
This chapter describes.....
```

> ```
> The section list is:
>
>  - Section 3.1 name
>  - Section 3.2 name
>  - Section 3.3 name
> ```

```
And the text continues here...
```

Is there any automated way to produce that chapter TOC (highlighted) instead of building it myself with references to labels (I need it to be a clickable reference without page numbers)? The problem of doing it in a manual way is that each time I change a section I have to come back and adjust this part of the chapter. And I will need to do this to many chapters in my report.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/list-sections-of-chapter-at-beginning-of-that-chapter) question.

Comment: Wow, 3 identical answers in one minute (two now deleted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [minitoc](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minitoc/) package.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's up with all the world flags and map PDFs in that directory??