# Each chapter with own contents?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List sections of chapter at beginning of that chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/list-sections-of-chapter-at-beginning-of-that-chapter)

I'm wondering whether its possible to have each chapter of a thesis with its own
    **contents page**? I tried it using the next few lines, and everything works...except that the next main page is affected.

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
```

The idea is to have something like this (just an additional page, not to affect the main chapter page). However, the next page shows continuation of 1.3, doing '1.4 Introduction'

```
    --------------------
    Chapter One

    1.1 Introduction
    1.2 Overview
    1.3 Aims of thesis
    --------------------
```

Any ideas to break the link between the two pages?

Comment: Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/list-sections-of-chapter-at-beginning-of-that-chapter) question help?

Comment: @BrettHarry: Please tell us if the above linked question solves your problem (I think it does) so that we can close this page as a duplicate. This help to keep the site clean and tidy and avoids repetition. If it doesn't solve you problem completely please make a quick edit to your question and state what's missing. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried making the syntax as below, but that doesn't work in my thesis...could it be a conflict with some package I use?   `\documentclass{book}`
`\usepackage{titletoc}`
`\usepackage{minitoc}`
`\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1}`
`\setcounter{minitocdepth}{3} `

`\begin{document}`

`\dominitoc% Initialization`
`\tableofcontents`

`\chapter{bla}`
`\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc`

`\section{blubb}`

`\section{foo}`

`\end{document}`

Comment: @martin: Please don't close it yet, unless you need space urgently. I would like to return to it later next week and to try and solve it, as I'm travelling now.

Comment: @BrettHarry: No problem at all.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Please do not hesitate to flag for reopening if you still have issues. However, this looks really like an duplicate for me.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [minitoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Thank you for your contribution. Answers on this site should show complete solutions to the stated problems and should be largely self contained. Therefore it would be great if you could provide some example code on how to solve this task with this package. Thank you.