# Strange behavior with Minitoc and Listoftables (with Hyperref Loaded)

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a way to add a *local* table of contents of sections/subsections appearing within a chapter to appear at the beginning of each chapter immediately after the chapter title on the title page (think: chapter contents)?

I'm using the `amsbook` package. Neither `titletoc` nor `chaptertoc` load properly without errors. `minitoc` loads but produces no output, even after including the `\do`... command before the `\tableofcontents`.

*Edit* I've discovered that there is an issue with `\listoftables`. If present, then `\minitoc` doesn't output a table. If removed, `\minitoc` works fine.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{amsbook}
\usepackage{minitoc}


\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChRuleWidth{1.618pt}
\ChTitleVar{\raggedright  \huge }
\ChNameVar{\raggedleft  \Huge }

\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=subsection,plainpages=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents 
\mainmatter
%\listoftables

\chapter{Title} 
\minitoc
\section{Section Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see package `chaptertoc` or `minitoc`

Comment: See [List sections of chapter at beginning of that chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3001/2975).

Comment: You should provide a minimal example of code that "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following test document shows that **minitoc** works

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Abc}
\minitoc
\section{One}
x
\section{Two}
y
\section{Three}
z
\end{document}
```

As the **minitoc** manual says, the presence of `\chapter*` command can put out of synchronization the minitocs. In particular `\listoftables` is such a bad guy. Your test file should be

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{amsbook}


\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChRuleWidth{1.618pt}
\ChTitleVar{\raggedright  \huge }
\ChNameVar{\raggedleft  \Huge }

\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=subsection,plainpages=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents 
\listoftables
\adjustmtc
\mainmatter

\chapter{Title} 
\minitoc
\section{Section Title}

\end{document}
```

A warning in the log says that **fncychap** should be loaded *before* **minitoc**.