# minitoc not appear?

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I have this file

```
\documentclass [11pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize,it}]{caption}
\usepackage{bookman} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing 
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[left=30mm,top=30mm,right=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{cp1256}
\setcode{cp1256}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{array}
\setarab
\raggedbottom
\title{\center \textbf{AAAAAAAAA}}
\author{
Submitted by AAAAAAA \\

}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter*{\thispagestyle{empty} Declaration} 


This thesis is an account of research undertaken between February 2004 and 
October 2004 at The Department of Physics, Faculty of Science, 
The Australian National University, Canberra, Australia.

Except where acknowledged in the customary manner, the material 
presented in this thesis is, to the best of my knowledge, original and 
has not been submitted in whole or part for a degree in any 

\chapter*{\thispagestyle{empty} \begin{center} \vspace*{2in}  To my AAAAA \end{center}}
\chapter*{\thispagestyle{empty} Abstract}
\chapter*{\thispagestyle{empty} Acknowledgments}
\dominitoc 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\minitoc \newpage
```

The minitoc in not appearing after chapter!

What I missed?

Comment: Hi, please tidy up you code. It is not compilable. Make it as short as possible, kick out all packages, you don't need here and explain, what you would like to get exactly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the compilable code (from a duplicate question posted by the same user: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146925/minitoc-not-working) plus a solution.

You need to to add `mtcaddchapter` after `\listoffigures` and `listoftables`, like this:

```
\documentclass [11pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize,it}]{caption}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
%     \setarab
\raggedbottom
\title{\center \textbf{AAAAAAAAA}}
\author{
Submitted by AAAAAAA}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter*{\thispagestyle{empty} \begin{center} \vspace*{2in}  To my AAAAA \end{center}}
\chapter*{\thispagestyle{empty} Abstract}
\chapter*{\thispagestyle{empty} Acknowledgments}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} \mtcaddchapter                     %new code
\listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}   \mtcaddchapter                     %new code
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\minitoc \newpage
 \section{AAAAAAA}
 WEFWEFWEFWEFWEF
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an alternative, you could add `\mtcaddchapter[List of Tables]` instead of `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}` and similarly for the list of figures. See pag. 52 of the manual for other similar cases.

Comment: Gear! all the best

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not compilable for the moment, but I am giving you something to start with:

- The author line broke for me. Write `\author{Submitted by AAAAAAA}`
- You need an `\end{document}` as last line, but for sure you just let this away when copy pasting...
- The package `caption` has to be loaded in front of the package `minitoc`
- The package `fncychap` has to be loaded in front of the package `minitoc`
- The package `titlesec` is not compatible to the package `minitoc`
- Something is altering your `\chapter` command after the `minitoc` package has been loaded. Don't know, what causes this. Have a look on page 175 in [the manual](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/minitoc/minitoc.pdf)!

Comment: trying all that not solving the problem yet!