# Display a titletoc in the style of minitoc

Tags: titletoc, minitoc

I'm writing my thesis and for easy reading and structures, I'm using the `minitoc` package to display a *ToC* for each chapter.

When I get to the appendices however, the `\minitoc` doesn't work anymore (it displays nothing, but also doesn't give any errors). It works fine before the `\begin{appendices}` or `\appendix` (i.e. in regular chapters, as displayed below).

As a fix, I've tried using the `titletoc` package to recreate the `minitoc`'s style for appendices. I've gotten quite close but I'm not there yet.

Can you help me finish it? I think I'm still lacking:

- increasing margins left and right
- decreasing vertical line spacing
- *optionally*, stretching the horizontal lines by about 2 pixels. Since I'm only noticing because I have them side-by-side, nobody will notice when I use only one in the final document.

[image: MWE minitoc vs titletoc]

**MWE**

```latex
    \documentclass[11pt]{report}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{parskip}


    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge} 

    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %Use sans-serif font.
    \usepackage{minitoc}
    \renewcommand{\mtctitle}{Inhoudsopgave}
    \renewcommand{\mtifont}{\large\sffamily}
    \renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\small\sffamily}
    \renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small\sffamily}
    \renewcommand{\mtcSSfont}{\small\sffamily}
    \renewcommand{\mtcSSSfont}{\small\sffamily}
    % Add MiniToC package. 
    % Translate 'Contents' to 'Inhoudsopgave'
    % Change all fonts from default (serif) to sans serif - to equal the regular document font

    \setcounter{minitocdepth}{2} %show subsec's (2) up to this level in minitoc's. Paragraphs ("3*sub"sections) and lower don't show up
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %number subsubsec's (3) up to this level. paragraphs don't get a number.
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1} %show up to level 1 (sections), hide subsections (2) and lower in ToC. (used in combination with minitoc to show ToC's per chapter)

    \usepackage{titletoc}
    % What styling do I need here?


    \begin{document}
    \dominitoc
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Introduction}
    \minitoc

    % My Solution
    \startcontents[sections] {\large Inhoudsopgave} \vspace{-15pt}\par
    \noindent\hrulefill \vspace{-5pt} 
    {\small \printcontents[sections]{}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}} } 
    \vspace{-10pt} \noindent\hrulefill 
    % My Solution

    \section{One}
    \lipsum[1]
    \subsection{One One}
    \subsection{One Two}
    \section{Two}
    \subsection{Two One}
    \subsection{Two Two}
    \section{Three}
    \subsection{Three One}
    \subsection{Three Two}
    \subsection{Three Three}

    % My Solution
    \stopcontents[sections]
    % My Solution

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason `\minitoc` wasn't working in my Appendix chapters: if I included chapters before the command `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=MyBibliography]` then nothing was off. Including chapters after that command stopped `\minitoc` from printing anything, however.

From [minitoc not appear?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146461/minitoc-not-appear) I found the solution to add `\mtcaddchapter` afther the `\chapter{Chapter Title}` declaration (and before `\minitoc`).

**Note**: the command should only be entered *once* for every time `\minitoc` forgets a chapter.

*Excerpt from [https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Minitoc](https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Minitoc_)*:

> Note: Sometimes minitoc does not notice that a new chapter has been added, so that it writes the wrong minitoc's to the wrong chapters. For example, this is the case of `\addcontentsline` and `\listoffigures`. To avoid this, you can inform minitoc about the "new chapter" by adding the command `\mtcaddchapter`.

So:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=apa, urldate=short, style=apa, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
%
% Insert document contents here
%
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=MyBibliography]

% \appendix % < = = Doesn't show "Appendix A: SomeAppendix" but "A: SomeAppendix", though offtopic.

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{SomeAppendix} \mtcaddchapter % < = = THIS COMMAND < = =
    \minitoc
    \section{About}

    \chapter{DifferentAppendix} % < = = NOT REPEATED HERE
    \minitoc
    \section{Introduction}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```