# mini table of contents in article

Tags: table-of-contents, article, minitoc

How can I make a mini table of contents at the beginning of an article class document to be displayed like this:
[image]

To appear not at the beginning of the chapter but at the beginning of the article.

Actually I really don't know where to start from, I'll post the code without the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[tight,italian]{minitoc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{paralist}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}\title{\textbf{Teoria degli insiemi:\\variabili e domini di quantificazione}}
\author{\textit{Bla Bla}\\Università Bla bla \vspace*{-0.25cm}\\ Cdl in bla\vspace*{-0.25cm}\\bla bla}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Introduzione}
Nella teoria degli insiemi di Zermelo-Freaenkel (ZF) le formule sono espresse in un linguaggio formale classico del primo ordine con identità a cui viene aggiunto l'operatore di appartenenza `$\in$'. Nelle formule quantificate si assume che le variabili vincolate quantifichino liberamente su tutti gli insiemi, cioè su tutta la gerarchia $V$, che non è un'insieme. Solitamente però i domini di quantificazione sono costituiti da insiemi e non da classi come in questo caso. Cosa succede a livello matematico e quale sono le preoccupazioni filosofiche che accompagnano questa scelta?

[...other sections]

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Same as [List sections of chapter at beginning of that chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/list-sections-of-chapter-at-beginning-of-that-chapter)?

Comment: Yes, but at the beginning of the article, before it starts. I'm not satisfied with the normal table of contents because for a short article like mine it is too wide. I would like to have something like minitoc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `minitoc` this is very easy.

Use `\dosecttoc` to enable the generation a section - level - ToC.

`\secttoc` prints the ToC in place where requested.

To guarantee, that lower level structure commands are shown, set the counter `\secttocdepth` to the value appropiate for the request (here I used `3`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[tight,italian]{minitoc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{paralist}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\title{\textbf{Teoria degli insiemi:\\variabili e domini di quantificazione}}
%\author{\textit{Bla Bla}\\Università Bla bla \vspace*{-0.25cm}\\ Cdl in bla\vspace*{-0.25cm}\\bla bla}




\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secttocdepth}{3}


\section*{Introduzione}
Nella teoria degli insiemi di Zermelo-Freaenkel (ZF) le formule sono espresse in un linguaggio formale classico del primo ordine con identità a cui viene aggiunto l'operatore di appartenenza `$\in$'. Nelle formule quantificate si assume che le variabili vincolate quantifichino liberamente su tutti gli insiemi, cioè su tutta la gerarchia $V$, che non è un'insieme. Solitamente però i domini di quantificazione sono costituiti da insiemi e non da classi come in questo caso. Cosa succede a livello matematico e quale sono le preoccupazioni filosofiche che accompagnano questa scelta?

\dosecttoc

\section{Natural Sciences}
\secttoc
\subsection{Biology}%
\subsubsection{Molecular biology}
\subsubsection{Cell biology}
\subsubsection{Genetics}
\subsubsection{Development biology}

\subsection{Chemistry}
\subsection{Physics}


\nocite{*}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took exactly this code and compiled it in overleaf and no mini-toc was there :( What could be the reason for that?

Comment: This is not working!

Answer (score 1):

I was having some issues with user31729's code. As written, the min-toc did not appear on my computer.

I was able to simplify the example. In the below simplified version, the code works for me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secttocdepth}{3}


\section*{Introduzione}
Nella teoria degli insiemi di Zermelo-Freaenkel (ZF) le formule sono espresse in un linguaggio formale classico del primo ordine con identità a cui viene aggiunto l'operatore di appartenenza `$\in$'. Nelle formule quantificate si assume che le variabili vincolate quantifichino liberamente su tutti gli insiemi, cioè su tutta la gerarchia $V$, che non è un'insieme. Solitamente però i domini di quantificazione sono costituiti da insiemi e non da classi come in questo caso. Cosa succede a livello matematico e quale sono le preoccupazioni filosofiche che accompagnano questa scelta?

\dosecttoc

\section{Natural Sciences}
\secttoc
\subsection{Biology}%
\subsubsection{Molecular biology}
\subsubsection{Cell biology}
\subsubsection{Genetics}
\subsubsection{Development biology}

\subsection{Chemistry}
\subsection{Physics}

\section{Another Section}

\subsection{sub1}
\subsection{sub2}

\section{Third Section Section}

\subsection{sub1}
\subsection{sub2}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```