# Section TOC with mini-toc package in article class

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I came across [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201408/mini-table-of-contents-in-article/201411#comment1223164_201411),
which directly addresses what I want to do. I copied the accepted answer's code in to an [overleaf document](https://www.overleaf.com/6384953821wvrxshvfmgfk) and compiled but the desired (and in the answer presented) result fails to exists:

> There's no mini-toc and I get the following error message

```
Maintenance document---Describing {\mscpack} version~{\mscversion}},
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

In my editor, TexMaker I get the error message that I am trying to insert an empty secttoc.

Comment: Please add the minimal version of the code here. We don't like following external links.

Comment: @JouleV I used exactly the code provided in the only answer to the question I linked. If it's a tex.stackexchange page, is it still considered an external link?

Comment: Just remove the command % \bibliography{biblio} - if you do not use bibliography

Comment: @DenysPotapov Unfortunately, nothing changed :/

Comment: On your link - https://www.overleaf.com/6384953821wvrxshvfmgfk i click recompile and see the result document

Comment: @DenysPotapov There's no mini-toc after the section Natural Sciences as in the linked question's answer.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/6384953821wvrxshvfmgfk - now it showing. Probably not all the engines in overleaf support minitoc