# Mini TOC next to chaper

Tags: table-of-contents, positioning, titlesec, tcolorbox

I would like to place a mini table of context directly next to the chapter like in the following.

[image]

For compatibility reasons the toc should be created using `titletoc` as suggested in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9028/54364). The `tcolorbox` in the MWE is not a must.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \startcontents[chapters]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=.5\linewidth]
            \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \section{Section}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Section 2}
    \lipsum
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    \startcontents[chapters]
    \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
    \section{Section}
    \lipsum[2]
    \section{Another section}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you need this only for first chapter?

Comment: and I think that `minitoc` is compatibility with standard class

Comment: No, I need it for all chapters. 
I used the standard class is only for my MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{picture}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \startcontents[chapters]
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(.4\linewidth,2.5cm){\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.5\linewidth]
               \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
              \end{tcolorbox}}
  \end{picture}
    \section{Section}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Section 2}
    \lipsum
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    \startcontents[chapters]
    \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
    \section{Section}
    \lipsum[2]
    \section{Another section}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]