# Make a ribbon box with text in it

Tags: rules, box

I'm pretty novice in LaTeX and use overleaf to write.

Is there any way that I could do this kind of box with a arbitrary text in it that is not linked to any title or chapter - just a black box with plain text in it?

I've tried to modify this code in the answer, but I only seem to break it...

[How to make a chapter heading like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391278/how-to-make-a-chapter-heading-like-this?rq=1)

Comment: \rule[-15pt]{2cm}{1.5cm}\llap{\color{white} III }

Gets me closer, but can't really get it to appear at the very end of the side of the page

Comment: \hspace{13.9cm}\raggedleft\rule[-15pt]{3cm}{1.5cm}\llap{\Huge\color{white} III }

This seems to work, but seems like an ugly solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't specify your exact requirements, here's a simple ribbon version that puts a black box with white text to the left or right side of the paragraph text.

You can use `\ribbonsep` to specify the horizontal space between the text and the ribbon. A ribbon should always be used at the begin of a new paragraph, as it uses `\noindent` to get its placement right. That also means that you need to use `\indent` explicitly if the following paragraph text should be indented. Note that the code hasn't been tested much, so there are several chances for optimization/extensions here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength\ribbonsep
\ribbonsep=12pt

\newcommand\ribbonleft{%
    \noindent
    \llap{%
        \smash{\vtop{%
            \kern-\baselineskip
            \hbox{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\dimexpr 1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin-\ribbonsep][r]{%
                \Huge\textcolor{white}{\bfseries NOTE}%
                \rule[-5pt]{0pt}{\baselineskip}%
            }}}%
        }}%
        \hspace*{\ribbonsep}%
    }%
}

\newcommand\ribbonright{%
    \noindent
    \rlap{%
        \hspace*{\dimexpr\textwidth+\ribbonsep}%
        \smash{\vtop{%
            \kern-\baselineskip
            \hbox{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\dimexpr 1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin-\ribbonsep][l]{%
                \Huge\textcolor{white}{\bfseries NOTE}%
                \rule[-5pt]{0pt}{\baselineskip}%
            }}}%
        }}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\ribbonleft\indent
\lipsum[2]

\ribbonright\indent
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]