# The content (summary) does not match the correct subsection using minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

Basically, Using **minitoc** I created a list all of the sections within of each chapter in a small table of **contents** at the beginning of every new chapter. See the image for clarification.

However, due to the large size of the work (a book), which contains 10 sections divided into 3 parts, the indices of each section do not correspond to their proper section, in other words, are all disorganized and do not correspond to their respective summary, for example in the image presented, this summary corresponds to the content of section 5 and not to section 4.

Essentially I adapted this [template original](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/customizable-thesis-template-pdflatex-english/rdjdtrckcjzw#.WtRrpnXFLbg")!.

With this structure:
archive (changed) - [teipel-thesis-en](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ojsu6RvQx3e8emwsmo8vVMEBScRn-0Fn/view?usp=sharing")

main.tex (changed):

> > ```
> >  \documentclass[classic,hyperref,histinit,frontispiece,minitoc]{teipel-thesis-en}
> >  \UniversityName{X}
> >  \SchoolName{X}
> >  \UniversityLocation{X}
> >  \ThesisType{X}
> >  \title{\\XXXX:\\}
> >  \authorName{XXXX} 
> >  \supervisor{X}
> >  \thesisPlaceDate{May, 2018}
> >  \secondExaminer{X B}
> >  \secondExaminerTitle{X}
> >  \chaptercolor{gray!100!gray}
> >  \appendixcolor{gray!100!gray}
> >  \hyperlinkcolor{black}
> >  \titlecolor{black}
> >  \titlebackgroundcolor{gray!100!gray}  
> >  \coverpageimage{0.2}{logo/X.png}
> >  \UniversityLogoPath{logo/X.png}
> >  \UniversityBWLogoPath{logo/X.png}
> >  \LogoScaleFactor{1}
> >  \setFrontispiece[0.8]{chap10/fig10/X.png}{X}
> >  \AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
> >  \clearpage
> >  \section*{Appendices}
> >  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
> >  \counterwithin{figure}{section}
> >  \counterwithin{table}{section}
> >  }
> >  \begin{document}
> >  \maketitle
> >  \beginfrontmatter
> >  \thesisDedication{X}
> >  \include{acknowledgements}
> >  \blank{}
> >  \include{abstract}
> >  \tableofcontents
> >  \listoffigures
> >  \listoftables
> >  \listofalgorithms
> >  \beginmainmatter
> >  \blank{}
> >  \part{A}
> >  \blank{}
> >  \include{chap1/chap1}
> >  \blank{}
> >  \include{chap2/chap2}
> >  \blank{}
> >  \part{B}
> >  \blank{}
> >  \include{selectedpapers}
> >  \blank{}                
> >  \include{chap3/chap3}
> >  \blank{}
> >  \include{chap4/chap4}
> >  \blank{}
> >    \include{chap5/chap5}
> >  \blank{}
> >   \include{chap6/chap6}
> >  \blank{}
> >    \include{chap7/chap7}
> >  \blank{}
> > \include{chap8/chap8}
> >  \blank{}
> >   \include{chap9/chap9}
> >  \blank{}
> >  \part{C}
> >  \blank{}
> >  \include{chap10/chap10}
> >  \blank{}
> >  \appendices
> >  \include{appA}
> >  \blank{}
> >  \bibliography{IEEEabrv,references}
> >  \includeabbreviations{Acronyms}
> >  \printindices
> >  \end{document}
> > ```

Into each chapter I inserted for instance chap1.tex (changed)[image]:

> > ```
> > \chapter{Introduction} \label{chap1_introduction}
> > \minitoc
> > \hfill \break
> > \newpage
> > \noindent
> > \InitialCharacter{B}la bla bla...
> > \section{Objectives} \label{chap1_objectives}
> > Bla, Bla, Bla...
> > ```

Comment: your question is how to...?

Comment: Hello naphaneal, 
Yes, how to make the table of contents (minitoc) works in an organized way, that is, each table of contents correspond to its respective section.

Comment: like that? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/list-sections-of-chapter-at-beginning-of-that-chapter

Comment: Hello naphaneal, the problem is more complex than this. Let me explain...

I already have the minitoc in "work", the problem is that it is working erroneously.

subappendice in the Section 1 points to Section 4; Section 2 points tor Section 5; Section 3 points to Section 6; Section 4 points to Section 7; Section 5 points to Section 8; Section 8 points to Appendices; Section 9 and 10  points to nothing

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!
SOLUTION: 
in the file named teipel-thesis-en.cls. 
In the line: \setcounter{mtc} {3} was 3, that is, the index was only beginning to be counted from section 3. I changed it to 0 and it is now working correctly.
        \newcommand\beginmainmatter{%
      \ifhyperrefoption
 % do nothing
 \else
  \mainmatter
 \fi
 \ifminitocoption
  \setcounter{mtc}{0}
 \fi 
}

Thank you all!