# list of tables and list of figures for each chapter

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, lists

I'm working on my these and I would like to have for each chapter its own bibliography, its own list of tables and its own list of figures.

For the bibliography I'm using ***chapterbib*** package : I've a *main* document plus two others for both of chapters so I can use the command *\include*{chapter} in the main document.

However, my problem still is the use of **lot** and **lof**. I'm not that familiar with LateX yet so I am asking help. For exemple, if I apply *\listoffigures* in the first chapter it displays to me all the figures that are in chapter 1 and chapter 2 .

How can I avoid this and get for each chapter its own lists ?

Here is the main document's commands :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, french, openright, oneside, fleqn]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}


% ----------------------------------
% -------- PACKAGES BIBLIO --------- 
% ----------------------------------

  \usepackage{chapterbib}
  \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
% \setcitestyle{authoryear,open={((},close={))}}

% *********************************************

\title{}
\author{} \date{}


% -----------------------------------------
% ------ B E G I N  D O C U M E N T -------
% -----------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle 


% ---------------------------------------------
% -------------- TABLE OF CONTENT --------------
% ---------------------------------------------

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire} 
\tableofcontents



\pagestyle{plain}


\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a FAQ and here are some links.

[TeXFAQ:  minitoc](http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minitoc)

[TeX.SE:  List sections of chapter at beginning of that chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/list-sections-of-chapter-at-beginning-of-that-chapter)