# how to remove Toc in chapters like the picture below

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]

```
\chapterauthor{Anik Ariami}{}
%\chapterauthor{Second Author}{Second Author Affiliation}
\chapter{Efektivitas Media E Book Creative  dalam Pemahaman Konsep Pencacahan}
\chaptermark{E book Creative Dalam Konsep Pencacahan}


\section{Pendahuluan}

Sejak merebaknya pandemi yang disebabkan oleh virus Corona di Indonesia, banyak cara yang dilakukan oleh pemerintah untuk mencegah penyebarannya. Salah satunya adalah melalui surat edaran sekjen kemendikbud no 15 tahun 2020  tentang pedoman penyelenggaraan belajar dari rumah dalam masa darurat penyebaran (Covid-19). Melalui surat edaran teresebut pihak Kemendikbud memberikan instruksi kepada sekolah untuk menyelenggarakan pembelajaran jarak jauh dan menyarankan siswa untuk belajar dari rumah masing-masing. Covid-19 merupakan penyakit dengan tingkat penyebaran yang tergolong cepat. Penyakit ini disebabkan oleh virus Corona yang secara khusus menyerang sistem pernafasan manusia [1]. 

Pengendalian penyakit menular dapat dilakukan dengan meminimalisir kontak antara orang yang terinfeksi dengan orang-orang yang rentan ditulari [2]. Menjaga jarak untuk mengurangi kontak fisik yang berpotensi menularkan penyakit dikenal dengan istilah social distancing [3]. Pembelajaran harus dilaksanakan dengan skenario yang mampu meminimalisir kontak fisik antara siswa dengan siswa lain, ataupun antara siswa dengan guru [4]. Pembelajaran matematika di setiap jenjangan Pendidikan bertujuan membantu siswa memahami konsep yang di pelajari dan menerapkan berbagai situasi [5]. 

Pemahaman konsep (CU) memanifestasikan atau merefleksikan (\emph{reflects}) suatu kemampuan siswa untuk memberikan penjelasan serta alasan (\emph{to reason}) dalam konteks atau situasi (\emph{in-settings}) yang melibatkan pengaplikasian yang hati-hati dan terukur dari definisidefinisi konsep, relasi-relasi, atau representasi-representasinya [6]. Dalam pembelajaran matematika, konsep matematika merupakan dasar yang harus dipahami oleh siswa karena dapat membentuk pola pikir siswa secara matematis[7]. Pemahaman konsep adalah hal yang mendasari matemtika dalam kurikulum sekolah [8].

Pemahanan konsep merupakan kemampuan siswa memahami konsep dasar matematika menyatakan kembali konsep dengan bahasa sendiri dan mengaitkan konsep dengan kehidupan sehari – hari [9]. Pemahaman konsep mencakup lebih dari hafalan , tetapi membutuhkan kemampuan untuk mengaplikasikan pembelajaran sebelumnya di beberapa jenis pengalaman tak terduga [10]. Pemahaman konsep sangatlah penting bagi siswa agar dapat menyelesaikan masalah baik dari hal yang paling sederhana maupun hal yang kompleks [7].

Pemahaman konsep yang baik dapat mengantarkan siswa pada ketertarikan mereka terhadap suatu materi yang sedang  di pelajari saat itu [11]. Oleh karena itu kemampuan pemahaman konsep mmatematika sangat penting untuk di tingkatkan dalam pembelajaran matematika [12]. Penguasaan terhadap banyak konsep, memungkinkan seseorang dapat memecahkan masalah dengan lebih baik, sebab untuk memecahkan masalah perlu aturan-aturan, dan aturan-aturan tersebut didasarkan pada konsep-konsep yang dimiliki [13]. 

Belajar konsep berguna dalam pendidikan siswa , yaitu: konsep mengurangi kerumitan lingkungan, konsep membantu kita untuk mengidentifikasi objek – objek yang ada di sekitar kita, konsep membantu kita untuk mempelajari sesuatu yang baru, lebih luas dan lebih maju , konsep mengarahkan kegiatan instrumental, konsep memungkinkan pelaksanaan pengajaran, dan konsep dapat di gunakan untuk mempelajari dua hal yang berbeda dalam kelas yang sama  [14].

Untuk membantu siswa kita dalam mencapai pemahaman konsep (CU) matematika yang mereka pelajari membutuhkan suatu keseriusan kerja yang penuh, yaitu menggunakan sumber daya kelas kita (buku teks, bahan-bahan belajar tambahan, dan alat-alat peraga pembelajaran) meskipun untuk penggunaan hal-hal tersebut kemungkinan kita tidak atau belum dilatih [6]. Inovasi digital dalam bidang pendidikan berupa perubahan pembelajaran berbasis teknologi dan informasi (IT), salah satunya menggunakan media interaktif dalam proses pembelajaran  [15]. Penggunaan media interaktif sangat bermanfaat untuk meningkatkan kemampuan siswa dalam mempelajari suatu materi [16]. 

Salah satu media interaktif dalam proses pembelajaran adalah penggunaan e book creativ (Pembelajaran Online). e book creativ merupakan kegiatan pembelajaran yang melibatkan penggunaan perangkat elektronikdalam menyampaikan, menilai serta memudahkan suatu proses belajar mengajar secara interaktif kapanpun dan dimanapun. e book creativ meniadakan batasan ruang dan waktu serta dapat memotivasi siswa untuk lebih aktif dan mandiri mencari materi dan pembelajaran.Fasilitas yang ditawarkan e book creativ membantu guru dan siswa dalam berinteraksi atau berdiskusi tanpa harus melihat batas waktu pertemuan kelas.Siswa tidak terpaku lagi pada text book, karena di dalam e book creativ terdapat materi baru yang disajikan melalui lembar kerja, slide, maupun video pembelajaran.

Beberapa penelitian sebelumnya seperti [17]; [18];  [19]; [20]; [21] telah melakukan penelitian mengukur tingkat keefektifan media pembelajaran interaktif. Namun beberapa penelitian diatas belum ada yang meneliti efektivitas media e – book creative dalam pemahaman konsep pencacahan.

Media e – book creative ini bisa dijadikan juga sebagai media pembelajaran jarak jauh. Hal tersebut dikarenakan pembelajaran jarak jauh ini masih di anggap tidak lebih baik daripada pembelajaran langsung secara konvensional terutama dalam pembelajaran matematika [21]. Selanjutnya [22] mengatakan bahwa kemampuan pemahaman konsep matematika peserta didik perlu dikembangkan karena sesuai dengan tuntutan Kurikulum 2013 serta merupakan salah satu tujuan dari setiap materi yang disampaikan oleh pendidik, sebab guru atau pendidik merupakan pembimbing peserta didik untuk mencapai konsep yang diharapkan. Berdasarkan permasalahan di atas, maka dilakukan penelitian untuk menguji efektivitas media e–book creative dalam pemahaman konsep pencacahandi SMK Bayt Al–hikmah kota Pasuruan.

\section{Metode penelitian}

Pendekatan yang digunakan dalam penelitian ini yaitu pendekatan kualitatif, jenis penelitian yang digunakan adalah deskriptif. Penelitian ini bertujuan mendeskripsikan kemampuan pemahaman konsep matematika siswa melalui media e book kreatif. Penelitian ini dilaksanakan di SMK BAYT AL-HIKMAH Pasuruan, yang beralamatkan Jalan Patiunus Krampyangan Bugul kidul Pasuruan Jawa Timur 67127. Subjek peneitian adalah seluruh siswa berdasarkan rekomendasi dari guru matematika yang berjumlah 19 siswa. Materi yang digunakan adalah pencacahan.

Data yang digunakan diperoleh melalui kegiatan tes dan wawancara. Tes diberikan untuk mengukur kemampuan pemahan konsep siswa. Metode wawancara yang dilakukan pada penelitian ini adalah wawancara semi terstruktur, isi wawancara dari penelitian ini adalah pertanyaan-pertanyaan yang berhubungan dengan faktor-faktor penyebab siswa melakukan kesalahan. Dalam penelitian ini kemampuan pemahaman konsep matematika akan diukur dengan menggunakan indikator diantaranya yaitu [23].

Menyatakan ulang sebuah konsep dan mengklasifikasikan objek sesuai dengan konsepnya (Siswa mampu menuliskan semua makna kata yang diminta dan dapat menjelaskan secara tersirat).
\begin{enumerate}
     
\item Menyajikaen konsep dalam berbagai bentuk representasi matematis (Siswa mampu membuat model matematis yang tepat dari informasi yang disajikan.) 
\item Menggunakan, memanfaatkan, dan memilih prosedur atau operasi tertentu dan mengaplikasikan konsep (Siswa mampu menjelaskan prosedur atau langkah-langkah yang digunakan).
\end{enumerate}

Indikator pemahaman konsep yang digunakan dalam penelitian ini disesuaikan dengan materi yang digunakan peneliti yaitu pencacahan.

Teknik analisis data yang digunakan dalam penelitian ini adalah analisis data kualitatif : 
\begin{enumerate}
\item Reduksi data, dalam hal ini peneliti mengumpulkan data tes yang berkaitan dengan pemahaman konsep matematika siswa dalam menyelesaikan soal
\item Penyajian data, peneliti menyusun data yang relevan sehingga menjadi informasi yang dapat disimpulkan dan memiliki makna tertentu
\item  Penarikan kesimpulan, untuk mengetahui persentase kesalahan-kesalahan setiap indikator pemahaman konsep matematika dalam menyelesaikan soal dengan menggunakan rumus berikut: 
\end{enumerate}

Untuk mengetahui tinggi rendahnya persentase pemahaman konsep maka peneliti menggunakan acuan sebagai berikut [24]:

\begin{table}[t!]%2
\tabletitle[Short Table Caption]{Persentase Kemampuan Pemahaman Konsep Siswa}%}{%
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}l}
Persentase & Kriteria\\
\hline\\ [-1ex]
0 $\leq$ P $\leq$ 20 & Sangat Rendah\\
20 $\leq$ P $\leq$ 40 & Rendah\\
40 $\leq$ P $\leq$ 60 & Sedang\\
60 $\leq$ P $\leq$ 80 & Tinggi\\
80 $\leq$ P $\leq$ 100 & Sangat Tinggi\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\section{Hasil dan pembahasan}
Pada penelitian ini pengambilan subjek dengan melihat kesalahan yang dilakukan siswa saat mengerjakan soal tes yang berupa soal cerita. Dari hasil pekerjaan siswa, diperoleh data kemampuan pemahaman konsep siswa dengan melalui e book kreatif berdasarkan dari indikator kemampuan pemahaman konsep yang telah dijelaskan. Untuk lebih jelas, berikut hasil analisis jawaban siswa.

\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\item Menyatakan ulang sebuah konsep dan mengklasifikasikan objek sesuai dengan konsepnya (Siswa mampu menuliskan semua makna kata yang diminta dan dapat menjelaskan secara tersirat).


\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{chapters/BookChapter/figures/aniek1.jpg}
    \label{fig:Gambar 1.Hasil Tes Siswa}
    \caption{Hasil Tes Siswa}
\end{figure}
Berdasarkan hasil pekerjaan dari siswa di atas, terlihat siswa melakukan kesalahan tidak menuliskan semua makna kata yang diminta dan tidak dapat menjelaskan secara tersirat. Siswa hanya menuliskan yang diketahui 6 karyawan saja.


\item Menyajikan konsep dalam berbagai bentuk representasi matematis (Siswa mampu membuat model matematis yang tepat dari informasi yang disajikan). 
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{chapters/BookChapter/figures/aniek2.jpg}
    \label{fig:Gambar 2.Hasil Tes Siswa}
    \caption{Hasil tes siswa}
\end{figure}
Berdasarkan hasil pekerjaan dari siswa di atas, terlihat siswa melakukan kesalahan tidak mampu membuat model matematis yang tepat dari informasi yang disajikan. Siswa tidak mampu membuat model matematisnya pada pernyataan yang ketiga yaitu penulisannya terbalik .

\item Menggunakan, memanfaatkan, dan memilih prosedur atau operasi tertentu dan mengaplikasikan konsep (Siswa mampu menjelaskan prosedur atau langkah-langkah yang digunakan).
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{chapters/BookChapter/figures/aniek3.jpg}
    \label{fig:Gambar 3.Hasil Tes Siswa}
    \caption{Hasil Tes Siswa}
\end{figure}
Berdasarkan hasil pekerjaan dari siswa di atas, terlihat siswa melakukan kesalahan tidak mampu menjelaskan prosedur atau langkah-langkah yang digunakan. Siswa salah dalam menggunakan operasinya yang seharusnya menggunakan operasi penjumlahan
\end{enumerate}
Berdasarkan hasil pekerjaan dari siswa di atas, terlihat siswa melakukan kesalahan tidak mampu menjelaskan prosedur atau langkah-langkah yang digunakan. Siswa salah dalam menggunakan operasinya yang seharusnya menggunakan operasi penjumlahan

\begin{table}[h!]%2
\tabletitle[Short Table Caption]{Kemampuan pemahaman konsep siswa melalui book creative.}%}{%
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}ccc}
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Nomor Soal}& \\
    \cline{3-4}
{Indikator} & {Jumlah} & {1} & {2} &{total}\\
    \hline \\[-1ex]
1 & $\sum b$ & 17 & 16 & 33\\
& $\sum s$ & 2 & 3  & 5\\
2 & $\sum b$ & 11 & 14 & 25\\
& $\sum s$ & 8 & 5 & 13\\
3 & $\sum b$ & 14 & 14 & 28\\
& $\sum s$ & 5 & 5 & 10\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]%2
\tabletitle[Short Table Caption]{persentase dari setiap indikator.}%}{%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Indikator & Persentase\\
    \hline \\[1ex]
1 & 13,2\%\\
2 & 34,2\%\\
3 & 26,6\%\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Dari tabel diatas diperoleh persentase kesalahan dari setiap indikator pemahaman konsep siswa. Kesalahan untuk indikator 1 adalah kesalahan dalam  menyatakan ulang sebuah konsep dan mengklasifikasikan objek sesuai dengan konsepnya mendapatkan persentase sebesar 13,2\% yang tergolong dalam kriteria Sangat Rendah, kesalahan untuk indikator 2 adalah kesalahan menyajikan konsep dalam berbagai bentuk representasi matematis mendapatkan persentase sebesar 34,2\% yang tergolong dalam kriteria Rendah, dan kesalahan untuk indikator 3 adalah kesalahan dalam menggunakan, memanfaatkan, dan memilih prosedur atau operasi tertentu dan mengaplikasikan konsep mendapatkan persentase sebesar 26.6\%  yang tergolong dalam kriteria rendah. 

Berdasarkan hasil wawancara yang dilakukan dengan mengacu pada kesalahan yang dilakukan siswa untuk indikator 1 kemampuan  siswa dalam menuliskan perrnyataan diketahui dan ditanya, rata-rata siswa kurang memahami soal yang diberikan oleh guru sehingga membuat siswa tidak dapat mengerjakan dan menyelesaikan soal. Untuk indikator 2 kemampuan siswa dalam mengubah soal ke dalam model matematika,rata-rata siswa tidak mengetahui operasi hitung yang digunakan siswa menuliskan operasi pengurangan yang seharusnya menggunakan operasi penjumlahan sehingga membuat perhitungan tidak tepat. Untuk indikator 3 kemampuan siswa dalam memilih prosedur atau operasi tertentu, rata-rata siwa tidak mampu melakukan prosedur atau langkah-langkah yang akan digunakan untuk menyelesaikan soal sehingga membuat siswa kesulitan dalam mengerjakan langkah berikutnya.

Faktor penyebab kemampuan pemahaman konsep matematika siswa rendah adalah siswa tidak menguasai konsep matematika dan faktor dari dalam diri siswa [25] Faktor dari dalam diri siswa adalah kebiasaan dan sikap-sikap belajar yang salah, antara lain kurang menaruh minat terhadap pekerjaan-pekerjaan sekolah, banyak melakukan aktivitas yang bertentangan dan tidak menunjang pekerjaan sekolah, menolak atau malas belajar, kurang berani dan gagal untuk berusaha memusatkan perhatianya.

\section{Kesimpulan}
Kesalahan untuk indikator 1 adalah kesalahan dalam  menyatakan ulang sebuah konsep dan mengklasifikasikan objek sesuai dengan konsepnya mendapatkan persentase sebesar 13,2\% yang tergolong dalam kriteria Sangat Rendah, kesalahan untuk indikator 2 adalah kesalahan menyajikan konsep dalam berbagai bentuk representasi matematis mendapatkan persentase sebesar 34,2\%  yang tergolong dalam kriteria Rendah, dan kesalahan untuk indikator 3 adalah kesalahan dalam menggunakan, memanfaatkan, dan memilih prosedur atau operasi tertentu dan mengaplikasikan konsep mendapatkan persentase sebesar 26,6\%  yang tergolong dalam kriteria Rendah. Berdasarkan hasil analisis diatas dapat disimpulkan bahwa pemahaman konsep siswa Smk Bayt Al-Hikmah Pasuruan rendah.

Faktor penyebab kemampuan pemahaman konsep matematika siswa rendah adalah siswa tidak menguasai konsep matematika dan faktor dari dalam diri siswa, faktor dari dalam diri siswa yang dimaksud antara lain; kurangnya minat terhadap pekerjaan-pekerjaan sekolah, banyak melakukan aktivitas yang bertentangan dan tidak menunjang pekerjaan sekolah, menolak atau malas belajar, kurang berani dan gagal untuk berusaha memusatkan perhatianya.

\section{Referensi}
\begin{hangparas}{0.5cm}{1}  

[1] H. A. Rothan and S. N. Byrareddy, “the epidemiology and pathogenesis of coronavirus disease (COVID-19) outbreak,” \textit{Journal of Autoimmunity}. 2020, doi: 10.1016/j.jaut.2020.102433.

[2] P. Caley, D. J. Philp, and K. McCracken, “quantifying social distancing arising from pandemic influenza,” \textit{J. R. Soc. Interface}, 2008, doi: 10.1098/rsif.2007.1197.

[3] S. Bell, C. Douce, S. Caeiro, A. Teixeira, R. Martín-Aranda, and D. Otto, “sustainability and distance learning: a diverse European experience?,” \textit{Open Learn}., 2017, doi: 10.1080/02680513.2017.1319638.

[4] F. Firman and S. Rahayu, “pembelajaran online di tengah pandemi covid-19,” \textit{Indones. J. Educ. Sci}., 2020, doi: 10.31605/ijes.v2i2.659.

[5] R. Rahmazatullaili, C. M. Zubainur, and S. Munzir, “kemampuan berpikir kreatif dan pemecahan masalah siswa melalui penerapan model project based learning,” \textit{Beta J. Tadris Mat.}, 2017, doi: 10.20414/betajtm.v10i2.104.

[6] B. Mulyono and H. Hapizah, “pemahaman konsep dalam pembelajaran matematika,” \emph{Kalamatika J. Pendidik. Mat}., 2018, doi: 10.22236/kalamatika.vol3no2.2018pp103-122.

[7] M. Fitria, B. Kartasasmita, and I. I. Supianti, “analisis kemampuan pemahaman konsep matematis siswa yang menggunakan model pembelajaran reciprolcal teaching,” \textit{J. Prism.}, vol. 8, no. 2, pp. 124–134, 2019.

[8] J. Mulligan, L. English, M. Mitchelmore, and G. Robertson, “implementing a Pattern And Structure Mathematics Awareness Program (PASMAP) in kindergarten,” 2010.

[9] N. M. Crooks and M. W. Alibali, “defining and measuring conceptual knowledge in mathematics,” \textit{Developmental Review}. 2014, doi: 10.1016/j.dr.2014.10.001.

[10] H. Saricayir, S. Ay, A. Comek, G. Cansiz, and M. Uce, “determining students’ conceptual understanding level of thermodynamics,” \textit{J. Educ. Train. Stud.}, 2016, doi: 10.11114/jets.v4i6.1421.

[11] S. Sarniah, C. Anwar, and R. W. Y. Putra, “pengaruh model pembelajaran auditory intellectually repetition terhadap kemampuan pemahaman konsep matematis,” \textit{J. Medives  J. Math. Educ. IKIP Veteran Semarang}, 2019, doi: 10.31331/medivesveteran.v3i1.709.

[12] R. Ramadhani, “Peningkatan kemampuan pemahaman konsep dan kemampuan pemecahan masalah matematika siswa sma melalui guided discovery learning berbatuan autograph,” \textit{J. Penelit. dan Pembelajaran Mat.}, 2017, doi: 10.30870/jppm.v10i2.2032.

[13] A. P. Fajar, K. Kodirun, S. Suhar, and L. Arapu, “analisis kemampuan pemahaman konsep matematis siswa kelas viii SMP Negeri 17 Kendari,” \textit{J. Pendidik. Mat.}, 2019, doi: 10.36709/jpm.v9i2.5872.

[14] Ernawati, “analisis kemampuan pemahaman konsep matematika siswa MTS Negeri Parung kelas vii dalam materi segitiga dan segi empat,” \textit{Skripsi}, 2016.

[15] D. Of et al., “pengembangan media pembelajaran e-learning berbasis website pada materi persamaan dan fungsi kuadrat,” vol. IX, pp. 17–24, 2020.

[16] N. Farida and S. Rahayu, “Perbedaan pembelajaran melalui multimedia interaktif dan melalui buku teks terhadap hasil belajar siswa pada materi pecahan kelas iv SDN GADANG 01 MALANG,” \textit{J. Inspirasi Pendidik.}, 2017, doi: 10.21067/jip.v7i1.1550.

[17] A. D. Rachmawati, B. Baiduri, and M. M. Effendi, “efektifitas media pembelajaran interaktif berbantuan web dalam mengembangkan Kemampuan berpikir kreatif,” \textit{AKSIOMA J. Progr. Stud. Pendidik. Mat.}, 2020, doi: 10.24127/ajpm.v9i3.3014.

[18] B. A. PRAYOGO, “Permainan Monopoli Sebagai media pembelajaran matematika,” \textit{Joyf. Learn. J.}, 2019, doi: 10.15294/jlj.v6i4.18864.

[19] R. U. Hasanah, “efektivitas multimedia interaktif untuk meningkatkan kemampuan Penalaran geometris siswa kelas viii,” \textit{AXIOM  J. Pendidik. dan Mat.}, 2019, doi: 10.30821/axiom.v8i1.5445.

[20] Mustakim, “efektivitas pembelajaran daring menggunakan media online selama pandemi covid-19 pada mata pelajaran matematika the effectiveness of e-learning using online media during the covid-19 pandemic in mathematics,” \textit{Al asma J. Islam. Educ}., 2020.

[21] N. A. Yensy, “efektifitas pembelajaran statistika matematika melalui media Whatsapp Group ditinjau dari hasil belajar mahasiswa (Masa pandemik Covid 19),” \textit{J. Pendidik. Mat. Raflesia}, 2020.

[22] D. Andriani et al., “understanding the number concepts through learning connected mathematics (CM): a local cultural approach,” \textit{Univers. J. Educ. Res.}, 2020, doi: 10.13189/ujer.2020.080340.

[23] Suraji, Maimunah, and S. Saragih, “analisis kemampuan pemahaman konsep matematis dan kemampuan pemecahan masalah matematis siswa SMP pada materi sistem persamaan linear dua variabel ( SPLDV ),” vol. 4, no. 1, pp. 9–16, 2018, doi: 10.24014/sjme.v3i2.3897.

[24] Arikunto, “Suharsimi Arikunto.pdf,” in \textit{prosedur penelitian suatu pendekatan praktik-revisi ke X}, 2010.

[25] D. S. Fitri Novi Astuti, Edy Yusmin, “analisis kesulitan pemahaman konseptual siswa dalam menyelesaikan soal pada materi peluang di MAN SANGGAU,” \textit{jurnal.untan.ac.id}, 2015.
\end{hangparas}

%Contoh untuk kutipan langsung
%\begin{VF}
%``A Process is a structured, measured set of activities designed to produce a specific output for a particular customer''

%\VA{Thomas Davenport}{Senior Adjutant to the Junior Marketing VP}
%\end{VF}



%contoh naskah dalam box
%\begin{shortbox}
%\Boxhead{Box Title Here}
%Another family aims at achieving the \emph{uninformative principle}: The published table should provide the attacker with little additional information beyond the background knowledge. There should not be a large difference between the prior and posterior beliefs.
%\end{shortbox}

%A fundamental notion \cite{yao2002can} is
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please make your code fragment **(i)** much shorter and **(ii)** extend it to complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [List sections of chapter at beginning of that chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3001/5764)