# How to recreate this output for chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

[image]

Hi, I want to make this output where below the chapter there is like a small table of contents, with the sections, subsection and sections. Thanks and let me know where to start or look.

Comment: see (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/list-sections-of-chapter-at-beginning-of-that-chapter)

Comment: You could also consider `etoc` package. The learning curve may be quite steep, but it's extremely flexible.